# mongo: find non-superseded documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with documents like:

```
{
        "_id" : "ThisIsASampleId_rand12345",
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-04-30T10:53:34.515Z"),
        "mySpecialId" : "specialId_12345",
        "status" : "error",
}
```

My goal is to find all documents with `{status: 'error'}`, so long as no subsequent documents exist with the same `mySpecialId` and `status` `'success'`.

Clearly I can do `db.jobs.find({status: 'error'})`, but after that, I get lost.

Do I need to do a `$lookup` in an aggregation pipeline into the same collection, using `"mySpecialId"` as both local and foreign fields, with a `$match` that includes something like `{$gt: {timestamp: $PREVIOUS_TIMESTAMP}}`?  That feels wrong, somehow.

Is there a simpler/better/more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) your collection by `timestamp` field and then run [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) with [$last](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/index.html) operator to get most recent document for each `mySpecialId`. Then you can simply check if that last document's `status` is `error`. If not then either all documents in this group had `success` or `error` appeared by was superseded with `success`. To get back original shape of your documents you can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html).

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $sort: { timestamp: 1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$mySpecialId",
            lastDoc: { $last: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "lastDoc.status": "error"
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$lastDoc"
        }
    }
])
```